# Как стримить содержимое окон различных программ в Win Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, потоки-данных

Мне нужно чтобы в моей программе отображалось то же что и в окне другой программы запущенной на этом же пк. Есть ли какие то библиотеки или стандартные методы? Буду рад любой помощи, три часа уже нагуглить не могу(

Comment: ключевые слова для поиска `c# capture window`

Comment: гляньте в сторону spy++

Comment: http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/05/4495.aspx

Comment: DWM работает, однако на Win10 при резком сдвиге некоторых приложений пропадает отрисованная миниатюра